# Moving from CEWP to SPFx - import fabric components

Tags: sharepoint-online, jquery, spfx, spfx-webparts, fabric

Been struggling with this for the past few days. I am quite new to Sharepoint development. Got my head around CEWP and was using office-ui-fabric-js components with code samples from [here](https://dev.office.com/fabric-js#).

I am now trying to move across to SPFx to create a simple comments app with a dropdown to select a category for each comment but am having trouble initialising any components (Buttons, dropdowns etc).

I set up my project following the steps outlined in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dTLsNcdOzxo) video.

My config.json looks like this:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://dev.office.com/json-schemas/spfx-build/config.2.0.schema.json",
  "version": "2.0",
  "bundles": {
    "comments-app-web-part": {
      "components": [
        {
          "entrypoint": "./lib/webparts/commentsApp/CommentsAppWebPart.js",
          "manifest": "./src/webparts/commentsApp/CommentsAppWebPart.manifest.json"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "externals": {
    "@microsoft/sp-client-base":
    "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-client-base/dist/sp-client-base.js",
    "@microsoft/sp-client-preview":
    "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-client-preview/dist/sp-webpart-base.js",
    "@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core":
    "node_modules/@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/office-ui-fabric-core.js",
    "jquery": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js",
    "fabric": {
        "path": "https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/js/fabric.min.js",
        "globalName": "fabric"
      },
  },
  "localizedResources": {
    "CommentsAppWebPartStrings": "lib/webparts/commentsApp/loc/{locale}.js"
  }
}
```

I then import it in my CommentsAppWebPart.ts

```
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';
import * as fabric from 'fabric';
```

load the fabric components css

```
protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
       SPComponentLoader.loadCss('https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css');
        return super.onInit();
      }
```

Initialise the components as outlined on the office-ui-fabric-js site and, despite getting the following error in the chrome dev console:

```
fabric.min.js:8 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 

    'addEventListener' of null
        at e._addListeners (fabric.min.js:8)
        at new e (fabric.min.js:8)
        at o.comment (comments-app-web-part_f851afe5c0521311e6aa18c8811908f4.js:1)
        at o.render (comments-app-web-part_f851afe5c0521311e6aa18c8811908f4.js:1)
        at o.t._renderWithAccessibleTitle (sp-pages-assembly_en-us_9e4f532e8d1f65fabd8d5bb4496d5640.js:736)
        at sp-pages-assembly_en-us_9e4f532e8d1f65fabd8d5bb4496d5640.js:736
        at <anonymous>
```

the components all render and function as expected
[image]

However, the styling for all the other apps on the page get messed up.

So I removed the function to load the CSS and instead imported it into CommentsAppWebPart.module.scss

```
@import url('https://static2.sharepointonline.com/files/fabric/office-ui-fabric-js/1.4.0/css/fabric.components.min.css');
```

But now none of my fabric components get initialised.

[image]

I read that fabric components has been moved to fabric-core and that should be used instead. I have tried this by importing from cdn, installing the fabric core npm package etc but nothing seems to work and also led to some jquery related errors so I reverted to the steps outlined above.

Any help would be much appreciated. I sense there is something fundamental that I am missing

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft has a post published on integrating the Office UI Fabric to SPFx.

- [Using Office UI Fabric Core and Fabric React in SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/office-ui-fabric-integration)

I think you were on the right track trying to import to your SASS file.  Make sure the NPM package is installed (`sp-office-ui-fabric-core`) and import from the correct location.

`@import '~@microsoft/sp-office-ui-fabric-core/dist/sass/SPFabricCore.scss';`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but it still doesn't initialise the components.
It also doesn't create a reference to the fabricui classes in the CommentsAppWebPart.module.scss.ts that gets generated when I build.
I don't know where to go from here. It appears the import is not working but can't figure out why not.